# Perl - reading in multi-line records from config file

Tags: perl

I'm trying to read in a multi-line config file with records into a perl hash array

Example Config File:

```
    record_1
      phone=5551212
      data=1234234
    end_record_1

    record_2
      people_1=bob
      people_2=jim
      data=1234
    end_record_2

    record_3
     people_1=sue
    end_record_3
```

here's what I'm looking for:

```
$myData{1}{"phone"}  <--- 5551212
$myData{1}{"data"}   <--- 1234234

$myData{2}{"people_1"} <--- bob
... etc
```

What's the best way to read this in?  Module?  Regex with multi-line match?  Brute force?  I'm up in the air on where to head next.

Comment: Why don't you show your attempt, and we can comment?  Otherwise, it's like doing your homework for you (whether or not this is homework).

Comment: That's a really weird config file format. The perl module [Config::Any](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Config-Any/) supports many formats, and I'd suggest you lobby whoever's outputting the format you're dealing with, to use one of the existing standards.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's one option with your data set:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %hash;
{
    local $/ = '';
    while (<DATA>) {
        my ($rec) = /record_(\d+)/;
        $hash{$rec}{$1} = $2 while /(\S+)=(.+)/g;
    }
}

print Dumper \%hash;

__DATA__
record_1
    phone=5551212
    data=1234234
end_record_1

record_2
    people_1=bob
    people_2=jim
    data=1234
end_record_2

record_3
    people_1=sue
end_record_3
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '1' => {
                   'data' => '1234234',
                   'phone' => '5551212'
                 },
          '3' => {
                   'people_1' => 'sue'
                 },
          '2' => {
                   'people_1' => 'bob',
                   'data' => '1234',
                   'people_2' => 'jim'
                 }
        };
```

Setting `local $/ = ''` results in an empty line being treated as a "record separator" in your data set, so we can use regexs on those records to grab the information for the hash keys/values.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nicely done. I was writing something similar and didn't think to use the `while /(\S+)=(.+)/g`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of modules for this, so the best practice is (as usual) to use them rather than re-invent the wheel.

From the snippet of the config file you posted, it looks like `Config::Simple` may be the best choice. If you can simplify the config format, then `Config::Tiny` would be easier to use. If things get more complicated, then you may have to use `Config::General`.

http://metacpan.org/pod/Config::Tiny

http://metacpan.org/pod/Config::Simple

http://metacpan.org/pod/Config::General

Answer (score 0):

Read it in one line at a time.

When you see a new record, add a new empty associative array to `myData` and grab a reference to it - this will be your "current record".

Now when you see key/value pairs on a line, you can add that to the current record array (if there is one)

When you see the end of a record, you just clear the reference to the current record.